# Webapi always returning 401 on remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have created an api using webapi 2 that is configured as below

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

             config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ControllerAndAction",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
            );



            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAPIRequest());
            config.Filters.Add(new AddCorsHeader());
            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new EncodingDelegateHandler());

        }
```

It works fine locally. However when I put it on a remote server, all requests return a 401 unauthorized error.  However, the bin files and web.config files are exactly the same.  Digging deeper, I added tracing to the remote server, and uncovered the following

```
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=AuthorizeAPIRequest.OnAuthorizationAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=askTheExpertController.ExecuteAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=EncodingDelegateHandler.SendAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
```

Essentially, the request is not even allowed authorization into the authorization method on the remote server! Locally the trace log looks as follows

```
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=AuthorizeAPIRequest.OnAuthorizationAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Parameter 'values' bound to the value 'LifespeakUserAdmin.Models.LifespeakAssetQueryValues'', Operation=ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Model state is valid. Values: values=LifespeakUserAdmin.Models.LifespeakAssetQueryValues', Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
```

I have verified the both the dll and the webconfig files on both the local and remote servers are identical.  What else could be accounting for this? Is there any way to 'force' the application to allow access to these methods?

**UPDATE: I was able to get this to work simply by changing the hostname binding in IIS.  The host was using the TLD .rocks -- when I changed it to .com. It magically worked -- they're both pointing to the same site, so not sure why this would be the case**

Comment: Can you access your endpoint methods from the browser?

Comment: Maybe a `CORS` issue?

Comment: What do you have in your startup.cs or global.asax file?

Comment: It's definitely not a CORS issue, because I'm accessing the endpoint directly through Fiddler -- on the local I get the JSON data, but on remote server, I got {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}.  I have updated my question with the code from global.asax

Comment: Please verify, that you have anonymous access enabled under Authentication in your remote IIS.

Comment: Yes AnonymousAuthentication is set to enabled for this website in remote IIS